# Como executar testes unitários no rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testes-de-unidade, rspec

Quando executo `rake spec` ele executa todos os testes. Como faço pra executar somente os testes unitários.

Comment: E como ele vai saber o quais são testes unitários e quais não são? Que tal usar `rspec` em vez do rake? Você pode passar o caminho dos testes unitários (se é que é o caminho que distingue os seus testes unitários), assim: `rspec --pattern spec/unit/*_spec.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode especificar arquivos específicos de modo que o RSpec só execute testes destes arquivos, por exemplo

```
$ rspec spec/models/*
```

Vai executar apenas os testes de models. Você também pode executar apenas um teste especificando a linha, por exemplo.

```
$ rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb:31
```

O que só vai executar o teste da linha 31 do arquivo user_spec.rb

Answer (score 1):

O Rspec testa comportamento, enquanto o Unit Test (supondo que seja essa ferramenta que esteje utilizando para teste unitário) testa as unidades da sua aplicação. Você não pode rodar testes unitários com uma ferramenta que roda testes de comportamento.

Se você deseja rodar apenas os testes unitários pode rodar o seguinte comando:

```
ruby -I test test/unit/
```

Comment: Meu RSpec deve estar com algum defeito, pois eu o utilizo para especificar e executar meus testes unitários.